# Framer Motion Animate Presence without conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I have the following React fly out navigation component using framer motion. This component is used multiple times for each navigation item.

Is there any other way to trigger this animation without conditional rendering (SEO)? Using `key` won't work, since I need it to be hidden by default and only visible when `isActive` equals true.

```
<AnimatePresence initial={false}>
    {isActive && (
        <FlyOutWrapper exit={{ opacity: 0 }} transition={{ duration: 0.2 }}>
            <FlyOutContent
                initial={{
                    x: "5rem",
                    opacity: 0,
                }}
                animate={{
                    x: 0,
                    opacity: 1,
                }}
                transition={{ duration: 0.3 }}>
                <Content>{title}</Content>
            </FlyOutContent>
            <FlyOutBackground
                initial={{ y: "-100%" }}
                animate={{ y: 0 }}
                transition={{ duration: 0.3 }}
            />
        </FlyOutWrapper>
    )}
</AnimatePresence>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want it to leave the DOM then you don't need to use `AnimatePresence` at all. Instead, you can animate the position (and opacity, etc) based on your `isActive` state. You can do this with [`variants`](https://www.framer.com/docs/animation/#variants) or just by switching between the properties directly.

Example (without variants):

```
<FlyOutBackground
    initial={{ y: "-100%" }}
    animate={{ y: isActive ? 0 : "-100%" }}
    transition={{ duration: 0.3 }}
/>
```

Example using variants:

```
const bgVariants = {
    visible: {
        y: 0
    },
    hidden: {
        y: "-100%"
    }
}
```

```
<FlyOutBackground
    variants={bgVariants}
    initial="hidden"
    animate={isActive ? "visible" : "hidden"}
    transition={{ duration: 0.3 }}
/>
```

Comment: I want the component to enter differently than to leave - from top to bottom on enter and fade out on exit - would that still be possible using your approach, because currently it seems that it's the same transition for enter and exit but reversed.

Comment: Yes, you would just need to define another variant to animate to, and probably a more complex state to determine which should be the current variant, but the concept is the same.